# Comparison between string in mongodb throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query

I am trying to compare strings in mongodb but it throws me exception.

My code is:

```
public WhiteBlackList GetWhiteBlackListByHash(string fileHashSHA256)
{
    try
    {
        IQueryable<WhiteBlackList> query = _mongoDbHelper.WhiteBlackList.AsQueryable();
        query = query.Where(list =>
                list.FileHashSHA256.ToLower().Equals(fileHashSHA256.ToLower()));
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Error($"Error while getting WhiteBlackList({fileHashSHA256})", e);
        throw new StateRepositoryException(e.Message);
    }
}
```

The exception message is :`{document}{FileHashSHA256}.ToLower() is not supported.`

I tried to compare like this:

```
query = query.Where(list =>
                list.FileHashSHA256.Equals(fileHashSHA256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

but it also throws exception.